# Intel Compiler - error: identifier "alignof" is undefined

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, icc, compiler-specific

I'm trying to run an example of the alignof operator.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Empty {};

struct Foo {
     int f2;
     float f1;
     char c;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "alignment of empty class: " << alignof(Empty) << '\n'
              << "alignment of pointer : "    << alignof(int*)  << '\n'
              << "alignment of char : "       << alignof(char)  << '\n'
              << "alignment of Foo : "        << alignof(Foo)   << '\n' ;
}
```

When I compile it with gcc (g++ -std=c++11 alignof.cpp) I get no errors.
But when I compile it with icc (icpc -std=c++11 alignof.cpp) I get the following errors and I don't know why:

```
cenas.cpp(13): error: type name is not allowed
      std::cout << "alignment of empty class: " << alignof(Empty) << '\n'
                                                           ^

cenas.cpp(13): error: identifier "alignof" is undefined
      std::cout << "alignment of empty class: " << alignof(Empty) << '\n'
                                                   ^

cenas.cpp(14): error: type name is not allowed
                << "alignment of pointer : "    << alignof(int*)  << '\n'
                                                           ^

cenas.cpp(14): error: expected an expression
                << "alignment of pointer : "    << alignof(int*)  << '\n'
                                                               ^

cenas.cpp(15): error: type name is not allowed
                << "alignment of char : "       << alignof(char)  << '\n'
                                                           ^

cenas.cpp(16): error: type name is not allowed
                << "alignment of Foo : "        << alignof(Foo)   << '\n' ;
```

I'm running the code on the same machine, and I change compilers with the module command.
How can the alignof operator be undefined?

Comment: Are you sure it's supported by the intel compiler? Having the c++11 switch is one thing but if they never implemented it that explains what you're getting here.

Comment: Well, it must be that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different compilers have different support for the new language features introduced in 2011.

According to [this table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport), Intel's compiler does not yet support `alignof`.

Comment: Hi, that makes sense, I didn't know that alignof wasn't supported. Thank you!

Comment: Is there an internal macro or similar for ICC? All modern compilers I am aware have it, you just need to know the specific keyword.

Comment: @jww: Are you looking for [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/281802)?